# Xna Pixel Collision and multi-layers. Early Collision, wrong detection?

Tags: xna, 2d, collision-detection, pixel, collision

we are currently working on a Xna game for college.
We are testing something first before we put in our own textures etc.

So we watch a lot tutorials and went through a lot of code.
Right now we have this little Program running:
http://www.konter.at/Konter_Game.rar

So this the GameScreen, where we load the player and the Background and everything we want to use.

```
namespace Casual_Game
{
    public class GameplayScreen : GameScreen
    {
        Player player;
        Camera camera;
        SpriteFont font;
        private List<Layer> layers;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

    Rectangle recPlayer, recGround;
    bool colis = false;
    Collision collision;

    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager content, InputManager input)
    {
        camera = new Camera(Game1.reference.GraphicsDevice.Viewport) { Limits = new Rectangle(0, 0, 4800, 720) };

        collision = new Collision();
        _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(Game1.reference.GraphicsDevice);
        base.LoadContent(content, input);
        player = new Player();
        player.LoadContent(content, input);
        font = content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font1");

        layers = new List<Layer>
        {
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.0f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.1f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.2f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.3f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.4f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.5f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.6f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(0.8f, 1.0f) },
            new Layer(camera) { Parallax = new Vector2(1.0f, 1.0f) }
        };

        // Add one sprite to each layer });
        layers[1].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer2") });
        layers[2].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer3") });
        layers[3].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer4") });
        layers[4].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer5") });
        layers[7].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer8") });
        layers[8].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer9") });

        // Add a few duplicates in different positions
        layers[7].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer8"), position = new Vector2(900, 0) });
        layers[7].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer8"), position = new Vector2(1400, 0) });
        layers[7].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer8"), position = new Vector2(2700, 0) });
        layers[8].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer9"), position = new Vector2(1600, 0) });
        layers[8].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer9"), position = new Vector2(3200, 0) });
        layers[8].Sprites.Add(new Sprite { texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/Layer9"), position = new Vector2(4800, 0) });

    }
    public override void UnloadContent()
    {
        base.UnloadContent();
    }
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        player.Update(gameTime);


        recGround = new Rectangle((int)layers[8].Sprites[0].Position.X, (int)layers[8].Sprites[0].Position.Y, layers[8].Sprites[0].Texture.Width, layers[8].Sprites[0].Texture.Height);
        recPlayer = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Image.Width, player.Image.Height);
        float elapsedTime = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            camera.Move(new Vector2(200.0f * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, 0.0f), true);

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            camera.Move(new Vector2(-200.0f * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, 0.0f), true);

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            camera.Move(new Vector2(0.0f, 400.0f * elapsedTime), true);

        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            camera.Move(new Vector2(0.0f, -400.0f * elapsedTime), true);
        if (recPlayer.Intersects(recGround))
        {
            if (collision.PixelCollision(player.Image, layers[8].Sprites[0].Texture, recPlayer, recGround))
            {
                player.Collision = true;
                colis = true;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Collision = false;
                colis = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            player.Collision = false;
            colis = false;
        }

        camera.LookAt(player.Position);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
       Vector2 parallax = new Vector2(1.0f);
        _spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,null , null, null, null, null, camera.GetViewMatrix(parallax));
        foreach (Layer layer in layers)
            layer.Draw(_spriteBatch);
        player.Draw(_spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Player X : " + player.Position.X.ToString(),new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "CameraX :" + camera._position.X.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 25), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "CameraY :" + camera._position.Y.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 40), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Col : " + colis.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 55), Color.Black);
        _spriteBatch.End();

    }
}
```

You see it is a Parallax Background with different Layers. On Layer[8] is the "Ground" where our player would run on later.

The Problem now is that the Collision Detection is not working correctly.
It looks like the detection is loading to slow or something.

We have in mind, that the player will hit the ground with the detection. So he has no value where he stops on the ground. So it has to be exate.

This is the Collision Class:

```
        public bool PixelCollision(Texture2D sprite1, Texture2D sprite2, Rectangle player, Rectangle enemy)
    {
        Color[] colorData1 = new Color[sprite1.Width * sprite1.Height];
        Color[] colorData2 = new Color[sprite2.Width * sprite2.Height];
        sprite1.GetData<Color>(colorData1);
        sprite2.GetData<Color>(colorData2);

        int top, bottom, left, right;

        top = Math.Max(player.Top, enemy.Top);
        bottom = Math.Min(player.Bottom, enemy.Bottom);
        left = Math.Max(player.Left, enemy.Left);
        right = Math.Min(player.Right, enemy.Right);

        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                Color A = colorData1[(y - player.Top) * (player.Width) + (x - player.Left)];
                Color B = colorData2[(y - enemy.Top) * (enemy.Width) + (x - enemy.Left)];

                if (A.A != 0 && B.A != 0)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

We would be very happy if someone could help us figure that out. 
We are not that much of programmers. So we thought asking doesnt cost anything. :)

K.

Edit:
Player.Update and Draw:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        moveAnimation.IsActive = true;
        inputManager.Update();


        if (inputManager.KeyDown(Keys.Right, Keys.A))
        {
            moveAnimation.currentFrame = new Vector2(moveAnimation.CurrentFrame.X, 2);
            velocity.X = moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        else if (inputManager.KeyDown(Keys.Left, Keys.A))
        {
            moveAnimation.currentFrame = new Vector2(moveAnimation.CurrentFrame.X, 1);
            velocity.X =  -moveSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity.X = 0;
            moveAnimation.IsActive = false;
        }

        if (inputManager.KeyDown(Keys.Up, Keys.W) && jump)
        {
            velocity.Y = -jumpSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; //Position += theDirection * theSpeed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            jump = false;
        }

        if (!jump)
            velocity.Y += gravity * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        else
            velocity.Y = 0;


        moveAnimation.Position = position += velocity;

        jump = moveAnimation.Position.Y >= 480;

        if (jump)
            position.Y = 480;


        base.Update(gameTime);
        moveAnimation.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        moveAnimation.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

Layer.Draw:

```
public class Layer
{
    SpriteBatch spr1teBatch;
    public Layer(Camera camera)
    {
        _camera = camera;
        Parallax = Vector2.One;
        Sprites = new List<Sprite>();
        spr1teBatch = new SpriteBatch(Game1.reference.GraphicsDevice );
    }

    public Vector2 Parallax { get; set; }

    public List<Sprite> Sprites { get; private set; }



    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spr1teBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, _camera.GetViewMatrix(Parallax));

        foreach(Sprite sprite in Sprites)
            sprite.Draw(spr1teBatch);

        spr1teBatch.End();
    }

    public Vector2 WorldToScreen(Vector2 worldPosition)
    {
        return Vector2.Transform(worldPosition, _camera.GetViewMatrix(Parallax));
    }

    public Vector2 ScreenToWorld(Vector2 screenPosition)
    {
        return Vector2.Transform(screenPosition, Matrix.Invert(_camera.GetViewMatrix(Parallax)));
    }

    private readonly Camera _camera;
}
```

Comment: Are player and ground textures changing often? If not, could you try extracting color data for those textures once (in `LoadContent()` for example), and then passing that data to your collision detection? Just so that you don't need to use `GetData()` every time.

Comment: Your collision code looks fine. What do you expect on a detected collision? You just set `player.Collision` to `true` and then? Btw, exact collision detection is very rarely a good idea because mostly Frame rate is changing which affects the movement of objects.

Comment: The Ground Texture will only be loaded ones I think, but the Player texture will be different with different moves and interactions.

Comment: @NicoSchertler player.Collision will be set to true, and then I try to use that, so the player stops at the point where he would collide with the ground.

Right now we have a gravity and a total value where the players stops.

Comment: Could you add the code for `Layer.Draw()` and `Player.Draw()`?

Comment: I assume the problem is caused by the different view matrix of the layers. Unless `groundRect` already contains this offset, you need to specify it somewhere else. Furthermore, avoid nested `spriteBatch.Begin()` calls like in `Layer.Draw()`.

Comment: And how could I do it?
And is there an easy way to get something like this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XliQy1wH0GI

Comment: Transform `enemy.Top` and `enemy.Left` with the appropriate view Matrix or use your `WorldToScreen()` method on `x` and `y`. The easiest way, although not the most efficient, to achieve your example is to move the player up as long as there is a collision with the ground.

Comment: Well this is the problem, the Player is moving above the groundlayer, because the collision detection is detecting collison like 250 pixel above the normal layer.
And I dont realy know how to use the Wroldtoscreen() method

Comment: Should I use the WorldtoScreen method for the Rectangle? I'am not sure what you meant for "transforming enemy.Top and left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's visualize what you are drawing:

[image: Visualization]

You draw the player at recPlayer.x, recPlayer.y on the screen. And you draw the layer at recGround.x, recGround.y. But this position is transformed by the view matrix.

What you now do is to iterate all intersecting pixels of the two rectangles. The resulting x and y values are in screen space. I have highlighted an example position for x and y. You now need to retrieve the colors of bot textures at this very position.

The color of the player can be retrieved pretty easily, because it already is in screen space. The positions in the texture is `xTex = x - recPlayer.x` and `yTex = y - recPlayer.y`. The index in the color array can be computed by `index = yTex * width + xTex`. You have already done this to access the color.

Retrieving the color of the ground is a bit trickier, because it is not in screen space like the player. It is probably translated and a bit scaled. You have not posted the code, how the layer's sprites are actually drawn. I assume, it is drawn at the position recGround.x, recGround.y (and then transformed). What we need to do is calculating the position of x/y in the ground's world space. So we use the method you already have:

```
var screenPosition = new Vector2(x, y);
var groundPosition = ScreenToWorldPos(screenPos);
```

This will basically invert the layer's transform. If it is translated by 20 px to the right, the new groundPosition will be 20 px left of the original position (because that's the position of the pixel that is actually at this position).

You can access the color just like you did for the player with `xTex = x - recGround.x` and so on.

Another problem I just realized is the computation of your intersecting rectangle. Of course, you have to use the transformed rectangle to get the real position.

---

Old post:

The problem is that the player and the layers are not drawn in the same coordinate system.

The player is drawn in the "default" system. The layers are drawn transformed with the according view matrix and are therefore translated, scaled and whatever.

In `PixelCollision` you iterate over all screen pixels that might intersect. These pixels are in the "default" system like the player. Due to this you can calculate the texture positions with:

```
texX = x - player.x
texY = y - player.y
```

However, this does not work for the layers. You have to transform `x` and `y` from screen space into the layer's world space.

```
layerPos = ScreenToWorld(new Vector2(x, y));
```

And then access the colors at `layerPos.x - enemy.x` and `layerPos.y - enemy.y`. This works, if you draw the layers at `enemy.x, enemy.y` in their systems. If you have an additional transform or draw them somewhere else, you need to consider this.

Comment: Should I do this befor I  create the Rectangle for the layer?
Or directly inside the PixelCollision Method?

Comment: In the collision method. You should pass the necessary additional parameters to it.

Comment: Okay, so I will do a "Vector2 layersPos" in PixelCollision.
Then I will call the ScreenToWorld method with a new Vector2.
and I will pass (x,y) from Layers[8].Sprites[0].Position(x,y)?

And then where put I layersPos.X - enemy.x?

Comment: Sry if I cant really follow.